# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\demology\errors.php on line 11

Tags: php

//I get the above error when I try to run my registeration page

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>

        <p> <?php echo $error; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Check if you have enabled `short_open_tag` in php configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, it may solve your problem..

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($errors as $error){ ?>

    <p> <?php echo $error; ?></p>
<?php } ?>

</div>
```